# SSIS Http Get Request Json Deserialize

Tags: c#, json, http, ssis, http-headers

I am attempting to retrieve data from a JotForm form using SSIS and it works only as far as getting a response, however the data is very messy and needs to be deserialzed. Below is a sample of the response (I put a breakpoint in the script and just copied the value into Notepad);

```
"{\"responseCode\":200,\"message\":\"success\",\"content\":[{\"id\":\"555555555555555555\",\"form_id\":\"2222222222222222\",\"ip\":\"195.195.176.147\",\"created_at\":\"2022-02-09 07:04:52\",\"status\":\"ACTIVE\",\"new\":\"1\",\"flag\":\"0\",\"notes\":\"\",\"updated_at\":null,\"answers\":{\"1\":{\"name\":\"standardForm\",\"order\":\"1\",\"text\":\"Standard Form Template UNIT-e\",\"type\":\"control_head\"},\"2\":{\"name\":\"submit2\",\"order\":\"20\",\"text\":\"Submit\",\"type\":\"control_button\"},\"3\":{\"name\":\"familyName\",\"order\":\"2\",\"text\":\"Family Name\",\"type\":\"control_textbox\",\"answer\":\"Michael\"},\"4\":{\"name\":\"givenName\",\"order\":\"3\",\"text\":\"Given Name\",\"type\":\"control_textbox\",\"answer\":\"Myers\"},\"6\":
```

Now, as you can see, it's pretty messy (for me, anyway) and what I am trying to retrieve is the givenName and the familyName. I have created a Script Component and below is the code in main.cs;

```
  public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mycompany.jotform.com/API/form/222222222222222222/submissions&apiKey=25555555xxxxxxxxxxx5555555");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string APIUrl = string.Format("https://mycompany.jotform.com/API/form/222222222222222222/submissions&apiKey=25555555xxxxxxxxxxx5555555");

        var response = client.GetAsync(APIUrl).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var data = serializer.Deserialize<ResultAPI>(result);

            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.FirstName = data.givenName;
            Output0Buffer.Surname = data.familyName;
           

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(response);

            Console.WriteLine(json);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);


        }
    }
```

I created two classes named Generic Response and ResultAPI like so (GenericResponse.cs);

```
namespace SC_98d911fb90f6449b86ed276a074f46c6
{
    public class GenericResponse
    {

        public ResultAPI[] ListData { get; set; }
    }


    public class ResultGen
    {
        public GenericResponse Result { get; set; }

    }

}
```

The ResultAPI Class looks like this;

```
namespace SC_98d911fb90f6449b86ed276a074f46c6
{
    public class ResultAPI
    {
        public string givenName { get; set; }
        public string familyName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The response is supposed to be to be sent to a Flat File Destination (.txt) which I have mapped, but nothing is actually being sent.

I'd be more than grateful if you could please help me get to the bottom of this.

EDIT: as requested, the JSON response is as shown below (I have only posted the first part as it exceeds the allowed character limit);

```
"{\"responseCode\":200,\"message\":\"success\",\"content\":[{\"id\":\"555555555555555555\",\"form_id\":\"2222222222222222\",\"ip\":\"195.xxx.xxx.xxx\",\"created_at\":\"2022-02-09 07:04:52\",\"status\":\"ACTIVE\",\"new\":\"1\",\"flag\":\"0\",\"notes\":\"\",\"updated_at\":null,\"answers\":{\"1\":{\"name\":\"standardForm\",\"order\":\"1\",\"text\":\"Standard Form Template UNIT-e\",\"type\":\"control_head\"},\"2\":{\"name\":\"submit2\",\"order\":\"20\",\"text\":\"Submit\",\"type\":\"control_button\"},\"3\":{\"name\":\"familyName\",\"order\":\"2\",\"text\":\"Family Name\",\"type\":\"control_textbox\",\"answer\":\"Michael\"},\"4\":{\"name\":\"givenName\",\"order\":\"3\",\"text\":\"Given Name\",\"type\":\"control_textbox\",\"answer\":\"Myers\"},\"6\":{\"name\":\"title\",\"order\":\"4\",\"text\":\"Title\",\"type\":\"control_dropdown\",\"answer\":\"Dr\"},\"7\":{\"name\":\"gender\",\"order\":\"5\",\"text\":\"Gender\",\"type\":\"control_dropdown\",\"answer\":\"Male\"},\"8\":{\"name\":\"dateOf\",\"order\":\"6\",\"sublabels\":\"{\\\"day\\\":\\\"Day\\\",\\\"month\\\":\\\"Month\\\",\\\"year\\\":\\\"Year\\\",\\\"last\\\":\\\"Last Name\\\",\\\"hour\\\":\\\"Hour\\\",\\\"minutes\\\":\\\"Minutes\\\",\\\"litemode\\\":\\\"Date\\\"}\",\"text\":\"Date of Birth\",\"type\":\"control_datetime\",\"answer\":{\"day\":\"13\",\"month\":\"08\",\"year\":\"1963\"},\"prettyFormat\":\"13-08-1963\"},\"10\":{\"name\":\"nationality\",\"order\":\"7\",\"text\":\"Nationality\",\"type\":\"control_dropdown\",\"answer\":\"AMERICAN SAMOA [796\\/2]\"},\"11\":{\"name\":\"address\",\"order\":\"8\",\"sublabels\":\"{\\\"cc_firstName\\\":\\\"First Name\\\",\\\"cc_lastName\\\":\\\"Last Name\\\",\\\"cc_number\\\":\\\"Credit Card Number\\\",\\\"cc_ccv\\\":\\\"Security Code\\\",\\\"cc_exp_month\\\":\\\"Expiration Month\\\",\\\"cc_exp_year\\\":\\\"Expiration Year\\\",\\\"addr_line1\\\":\\\"Street Address\\\",\\\"addr_line2\\\":\\\"Street Address Line 2\\\",\\\"city\\\":\\\"City\\\",\\\"state\\\":\\\"State \\\\\\/ Province\\\",\\\"postal\\\":\\\"Postal \\\\\\/ Zip Code\\\",\\\"country\\\":\\\"Country\\\"}\",\"text\":\"Address\",\"type\":\"control_address\",\"answer\":{\"addr_line1\":\"17 Clover Avenue\",\"addr_line2\":\"Bethesda\",\"city\":\"Kent\",\"country\":\"United Kingdom\"},\"prettyFormat\":\"Street Address: 17 Clover Avenue<br>Street Address Line 2: Bethesda<br>City: Kent<br>Country: United Kingdom<br>\"},\"12\":{\"name\":\"emailAddress\",\"order\":\"10\",\"text\":\"Email Address\",\"type\":\"control_email\",\"answer\":\"mmyers@gmail.com\"},\"13\":{\"name\":\"telephoneNumber\",\"order\":\"11\",\"sublabels\":\"{\\\"country\\\":\\\"Country Code\\\",\\\"area\\\":\\\"Area Code\\\",\\\"phone\\\":\\\"Phone Number\\\",\\\"full\\\":\\\"Phone Number\\\",\\\"masked\\\":\\\"Please enter a valid phone number.\\\"}\",\"text\":\"Telephone Number\",\"type\":\"control_phone\",\"answer\":{\"country\":\"+44\",\"area\":\"7888\",\"phone\":\"167989\"},\"prettyFormat\":\"(+44) (7888) 167989\"},\"14\":{\"name\":\"mobileTelephone\",\"order\":\"12\",\"sublabels\":\"{\\\"country\\\":\\\"Country Code\\\",\\\"area\\\":\\\"Area Code\\\",\\\"phone\\\":\\\"Phone Number\\\",\\\"full\\\":\\\"Phone Number\\\",\\\"masked\\\":\\\"Please enter a valid phone number.\\\"}\",\"text\":\"Mobile Telephone Number\",\"type\":\"control_phone\",\"answer\":{\"country\":\"+44\",\"area\":\"7499\",\"phone\":\"90377\"},\"prettyFormat\":\"(+44) (7499) 90377\"},\"15\":{\"name\":\"applicationSession\",\"order\":\"13\",\"text\":\"Application Session\",\"type\":\"control_textbox\",\"answer\":\"2020AC\"},\"16\":{\"name\":\"uniteAgent\",\"order\":\"14\",\"text\":\"UNIT-e Agent reference\",\"type\":\"control_textbox\",\"answer\":\"IFCELS\"},\"17\":{\"name\":\"uniteProgramme\",\"order\":\"15\",\"text\":\"UNIT-e Programme code\",\"type\":\"control_textbox\",\"answer\":\"Q3EP\"},\"18\":{\"name\":\"entryYear\",\"order\":\"16\",\"text\":\"Entry year\",\"type\":\"control_textbox\",\"answer\":\"2021\"},\"19\":{\"name\":\"entryMonth\",\"order\":\"17\",\"text\":\"Entry month\",\"type\":\"control_textbox\",\"answer\":\"04\"},\"20\":{\"name\":\"entryPoint\",\"order\":\"18\",\"text\":\"Entry point\",\"type\":\"control_textbox\",\"answer\":\"1\"},\"26\":{\"name\":\"postalzipCode\",\"order\":\"9\",\"text\":\"Postal\\/Zip Code\",\"type\":\"control_textbox\",\"answer\":\"KT1 3ER\"},\"27\":{\"name\":\"uniqueID\",\"order\":\"19\",\"selectedField\":\"528c8b464b1a424916000004\",\"text\":\"Unique ID\",\"type\":\"control_autoincrement\",\"answer\":\"8TYZ2Y\"}}}"
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: What is your question? Are you able to de-serialize your `JSON` that you get from the API?

Comment: @RahulSharma No I am not able to deserialize - the attributes in the response, for instance givenName, look like this ":\"givenName\" so what I am trying to do is to get the  values for givenName and familyName from the response.

Comment: The `JSON` string that you have posted is not correct so that could cause the issue? @GBM

Comment: @RahulSharma thank you for getting back to me so quickly - which Json string are you referring to? The Json string I posted at the very top of the question is part of the response - I just pasted that into the question to show what I get in the response. What I need from that Json string is to get the values of the givenName and family Name which are wrapped around the \" and the \". I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you post your entire `JSON` string in your question?

Comment: @RahulSharma please see edit in the question - I cannot post the entire Json response it's VERY long and exceeds the StackOverflow character limit. You'll see that from the JSOn response, what I should be retrieving is the givenName (Michael) and familyName (Myers). This is the first row of the online form I am trying to get data from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242041/discussion-between-gbm-and-rahul-sharma).

Comment: If you modify your Main to fire information events and add an else clause to also log when no data found, do you get any better diagnostic information out? https://gist.github.com/billinkc/a18ce7071a8c53dc03080409d039599b

Comment: Also, from your chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54021134#54021134  You mention Newtonsoft... If you've not installed the assembly to the global assembly cache, GAC, that's likely the source of your issues

Comment: It is uncommon that the escape backslashes are actually in the response. Is that really the case?

Comment: I am also unaware that you can use Async methods in SSIS. Consider a console app instead.

Comment: I also recommend using a site like https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp to create a c# object to deserialize into.

Comment: @KeithL Thank you for reply - yes, that's the case. The response is exactly as I get it when I make the Http request. The form is JotForm and it is really a strange format - I have not seen backslashes being used as escapes before and I think that's one of the issues I am having.

Comment: @billinkc Thank you - I will try and add the assembly references manually and see if that makes a difference. So far, uninstalling and reinstalling hasn't worked at all.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the `JSON` that you get from the `API` contains `\` characters in the `JSON`, so you need to deserialize as shown in the below attempt. Your `Model` structure will hold the dynamic nodes also.

For this, you need to use the `Newtonsoft` package which serializes and deserializes any .NET object. You can add this package through the `Nuget` manager in Visual Studio or add the reference manually in your project.

We also need a custom converter in your case to handle scenario when your `Answer` property can be a `string` or of `Answer` class type. It will set the value of `Answer` to null if it is a string and handle it accordingly.

A working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yB1fIf

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myString=@" "; //omitted for breveity 
        var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myString);
        Root myDeserializedClass1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myDeserializedClass);
    
        foreach(var items in myDeserializedClass1.content)
        {
            foreach(var items1 in items.answers.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(items1.name);
                //Console.WriteLine(items1.text);
            }
        } 
        
    }
}

public class AnswersData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string order { get; set; }
    public string sublabels { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(AnswerConverter))]
    public Answer answer { get; set; }
    public string prettyFormat { get; set; }
    public string selectedField { get; set; }
    public string full { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public string full { get; set; }
}


public class Content
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string form_id { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string @new { get; set; }
    public string flag { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public object updated_at { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,AnswersData> answers { get; set; }
}

public class ResultSet
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public int responseCode { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Content> content { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public ResultSet resultSet { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerConverter : JsonConverter<Answer>
{
    public override Answer ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Answer existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Null:
            case JsonToken.String:
                return null;

            default:
                var alarm = hasExistingValue ? existingValue : (Answer)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
                serializer.Populate(reader, alarm);
                return alarm;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Answer value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID
standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID
standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID
standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID
standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID
standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID
standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID
standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID
standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID
standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID




standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID




standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID




standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID




standardForm
submit2
familyName
givenName
title
gender
dateOf
nationality
address
emailAddress
telephoneNumber
mobileTelephone
applicationSession
uniteAgent
uniteProgramme
entryYear
entryMonth
entryPoint
postalzipCode
uniqueID
```

Comment: still no luck I'm afraid...

Comment: I got this working in the end and used a slightly different method. Managed to get Newtonsoft working and created some classes using https://json2csharp.com/ - I then deserialized the classes and that did the job. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After much head-cracking, I finally managed to get Newtonsoft working. I used https://json2csharp.com/ to generator classes e.g;

```
    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("content")]
        public List<Content> content { get; set; }
    }
    public class Content
    {
        [JsonProperty("answers")]
        public Answers answers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answers
    {
        [JsonProperty("3")]
        public familyName familyName { get; set; }
    }
    public class familyName
    {
        [JsonProperty("answer")]
        public string answer { get; set; }
    }
```

I then deserialized like this;

```
dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response);
```

This then allowed me to add each column to the Output0Buffer. Many thanks for your help and here's hoping this also assists someone.

Comment: Ahh, you only wanted the data from the `3` node. I did it for you in a dynamic way to handle as many nodes as there could be plus using a converter to handle the `Answer` property. Well as long as it serves your purpose, it is good that you got it solved for your scenario.

Comment: @RahulSharma I wanted the data from a couple of nodes - this method worked better. Thank you for the one you suggested, but I opted to not use it as this I ended up using was more simplistic and concise. Thank you for your assistance though.